# to check duplicate values for text box with same id onkeyup event

Tags: javascript

please help to validate duplicate values for the text box having same id which is in loop with onkeyup or onblur event, i need to validate before submitting the form,

N number of textbox generated in loop, in each text box i need to enter rank, thereby i need to validate that duplicate rank should not be entered after the value is entered into the text box,

`enter code here`

```
       <%Iterator iterator_t = tem.keySet().iterator();
   int i =0;
   while (iter.hasNext()) {
       String key_t = (String) iter.next(); 
           ModuleBean moduleBean = (ModuleBean) tem.get(key_t); %>
           <input type="text" name="rank1" id="rank1" size="2" "/>  
       <%}%>
```

Comment: This is not javascript (or it is an unspecified library). Please supply us with more information about what you are using.

Comment: Suggestion: it is not advisable to use same id for many elements, it must be unique.. U can use same class for many.

Comment: Several problems: 1) This is a JavaScript (client-side) question, so there is no point at showing us the server-side code, only the rendered client-side code. 2) IDs have to be unique in a HTML document. 3) You need to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use same id for it, instead add a class to it. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V4Sxg/5/)

```
<input type="text" name="rank1" id="rank1" size="2" class="rank" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="rank2" id="rank2" size="2" class="rank" value="2"/>

function find_duplicates(arr) {
  var len=arr.length,
      out=[],
      counts={};

  for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var count = counts[item];
    counts[item] = counts[item] >= 1 ? counts[item] + 1 : 1;
  }

  for (var item in counts) {
    if(counts[item] > 1)
      out.push(item);
  }

  return out;
}

$('.rank').keyup(function()
{
    var listOfValues = [];

    $('.rank').each(function()
    {
        if($(this).val()!='')
           listOfValues.push($(this).val());
    });

    var duplicates = find_duplicates(listOfValues);

    if(duplicates.length>0)
    {
        $('#result').html('Duplicates are:');
        $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(duplicates));
    }
    else
    {
        $('#result').html('No Duplicates found');
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work. jQuery returns only one element when using an ID selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Waqar Alamgi, it helped me